# What does `:first-of-type` really mean?

Tags: jsoup

Given the following HTML:

```
<p>paragraph text 1</p>
<p>paragraph text 1</p>
<div class="heading-h3">Category Title 1</div>
<p>1. <a href="#item1">
        <strong>Item One</strong>
    </a>
    <br>2. <a href="#item2">
            <strong>Item Two</strong>
        </a>
        <br>3. <a href="#item3">
                <strong>Item Three</strong>
            </a>
            <br>4. <a href="#item4">
                    <strong>Item Four</strong>
                </a>
<div class="heading-h3">Category Title 2</div>
<p>1. <a href="#item11">
        <strong>Item Eleven</strong>
    </a>
    <br>2. <a href="#item12">
            <strong>Item Twelve</strong>
        </a>
        <br>3. <a href="#item13">
                <strong>Item Thirteen</strong>
            </a>
            <br>4. <a href="#item14">
                    <strong>Item Fourteen</strong>
                </a>
```

I would like to use a **single** [jsoup selector](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html) expression that returns only the first element out of the two `<div class="heading-h3">`.

That is, if `select("div.heading-h3")` returns two elements and `select("div.heading-h3").first()` return only the first element of the two, I would like to use a **single** [jsoup](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax) expression that does not resort to [Elements.first()](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Elements.html#first()) to limit the result set to a single (first) element.

At first, I thought that `"div.heading-h3:first-of-type"` would accomplish that, but when tested, it returns **no elements** at all.

What am I missing in the interpretation of the `:first-of-type` "structural pseudo selectors"? Is it possible to accomplish what I want in a **single** `jsoup` selector? i.e. without resorting to [Elements.first()](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Elements.html#first())?

Comment: From your example, `div:first-of-type` might work. A "type" is the node name, for example, "div". "first-of" is relative to the sibling group. Though `div.heading-h3:first-of-type` should work, it might be that the addition of the class selector is confusing jsoup.

Comment: @Ouroborus Thank you. `div:first-of-type` returns all `div` elements in the HTML, not just the first one. I am trying to find a `jsoup` expression that returns only the first element without resorting to `Elements.first()`. Any idea how to accomplish that?

Comment: The kind of counting that psuedo selectors do is relative to the sibling group. There isn't a way to filter the selector's results as part of the selector. So you're not going to be able to accomplish what you want without either changes to the html or using filter functions like `.first()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attempting `div.heading-h3:first-of-type` (with the same exact HTML typed in the question) at https://try.jsoup.org/ actually works as I originally expected:

[image]

But in my Java program this doesn't work because the actual HTML being parsed by my program is **much larger**.

Assuming that the `jsoup` version at https://try.jsoup.org/ is the latest and greatest, I can only conclude that there are some practical limitations to `jsoup` which makes it behave **inconsistently** when dealing with **huge** or "difficult" (to `jsoup`) HTML.

[This comment](https://stackoverflow.com/users/319878/paul-grime) in a different SO thread suggests that *"jsoup can alter (fix) the DOM..."*, which to me means "consistency or correctness is not guaranteed".